# In Java, I've made a JPanel that uses paint(Graphics g), so the entire frame is filled. How do I make room for another panel below?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

http://chopapp.com/#vebagc7x

That's my current code.

If you run it, you'd see that the entire frame is filled up, and even though I can restrict where the orbs go easily, I don't see such an easy way to have a bottom panel with buttons and text on it, for user input.

Any advice?

Comment: most of answerers here are never going to check code placed anywhere ....,

Comment: One way is to set a single column `GridLayout` to the container.  A `BoxLayout` or `JSplitPane` might also be useful.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19487099/edit).

Answer (score 1):

`add` the bottom JPanel to the south portion of the screen with `add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH)`.